# why termux dont permission to create gitignore file in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, termux

I am trying to install `react` with `creat-react-app` but it shows the following error:

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/mya2/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/init.js:153
      throw err;
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/mya2/gitignore' -> '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/mya2/.gitignore'
    at Object.linkSync (fs.js:956:3)
    at tryRenameSync (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/mya2/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/move-sync/index.js:40:12)
    at Object.moveSync (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/mya2/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/move-sync/index.js:22:3)
    at module.exports (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/mya2/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/init.js:141:8)
    at [eval]:3:14
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:123:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:720:27)

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.
%
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to install react and create an app using create-react-app on Termux you have to do the following:

Install npx if you haven't done so:

```
$ npm install -g npx
```

Install create-react-app

```
$ npm install create-react-app -g
```

Clean your npm cache to avoid the 'ERR! cb() never called!' error

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

If you want to create an app called 'apprx' first create the folder and then open it:

```
mkdir apprx && cd apprx
```

now create the following file;

```
$ touch .gitignore
```

Go back up one level

```
$ cd ../
```

Run the 'create-react-app':

```
$ npx create-react-app apprx
```

It will take a while but it will setup. Once done:

```
$ cd apprx
```

Start the app

```
$ npm start
```

Tested this on a Huawei M5 8 and Samsung Note 8